# Ubuntu efi portable

Tags: 12.10, boot, 13.04, uefi, grub-efi

I need to install Ubuntu on my USB pendrive 3.0 in order to have my "portable computer" everywhere i go. BUT i need it to work also on EFI systems. I've tryied by installing ubuntu on a VirtualBox hd (the copy of the USB pendrive) and it works if i set the VM as EFI. The problem is that it doesn't boot on other computers. I've done a manual partition with this scheme:

32GB USB pendrive:

```
- 150 MB: efi partition (EFI BOOT)
- 258 MB: ext2 partition (BOOT)
- the rest: ext4 partition (root)
```

Any ideas why the bios recognize all the partitions but when i try to boot from the efi one nothing happens? If anyone can suggest me a guide or something useful for what i'm doing it will be very kind...

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: More information is required. As a start, try posting the output of `find /boot/efi -iname "*.efi"`, with your 150MB EFI System Partition mounted at `/boot/efi`; and the output of `sudo parted /dev/sdb print`, changing `/dev/sdb` to the USB flash drive's device file.

Comment: First, i'm sorry i've posted some wrong info and thanks for the answer.... Second I've runned the command you've told me in the VM and the output is:
output1: /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
output2:
Model: ATA VBOXHARDDISK (scsi)
HD /dev/sda: 32 GB
Sector dimension (logic/physic): 512B/512B
Partition table: gpt
Number - Start - End - Dimension - File System - Name - Flag
1 - 1049KB - 200 MB - 199MB - fat32 - EFI_boot - Boot
2 - 200 MB - 456 MB - 256MB - ext2 - - Boot
3 - 456 MB - 5456MB - 5000MB - ext4 - -

Answer (score 1):

Mount the USB flash drive's first partition (the ESP) at `/boot/efi` and issue the following commands (changing `/boot/efi` if you mount somewhere else):

```
cd /boot/efi/EFI
sudo mv ubuntu boot
sudo mv boot/grubx64.efi boot/bootx64.efi
cd ~
```

You can then unmount the USB flash drive and it should work.

---

**EDIT:** Since the above didn't work, try something more radical:

1. Download the binary `.zip` file version (*not* the Debian package version) of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and unpack the `.zip` file.
2. In a working boot of your USB flash drive, open a Terminal window.
3. Type `df /boot/efi` to identify the device file associated with your USB flash drive's ESP.
4. `cd` to the `refind-bin-{version}` subdirectory of the unpacked rEFInd. If you type `ls` you should see, among other things, a script file called `install.sh`.
5. Type `sudo ./install.sh --alldrivers --usedefault /dev/sdb1`, changing `/dev/sdb1` to the device file for your USB flash drive, as identified earlier.

In theory, at this point the USB flash drive should be bootable on more systems.

Comment: Still not working... The pc recognize the USB but when it tries to boot it shows black screen and flashing _

Comment: See my new suggestion, above.